# MySQL: Match columns from three tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables below. The primary key is the PK column. I want to get the unique PK on each tables and populate the NO column based on the PK (see output below). How can I do it using MySQL? Sorry for my question, I am just new to MySQL, i just know how to select those unique PKs.

```
 select U_IMSI from
 (select IMSI from table_A
 UNION
 select IMSI from table_B
 UNION
 select IMSI from table_C) as UNIQUE_IMSI
```

table_A

```
PK     NO  
12345  22222
78912  33333
56892  44444
```

table_B

```
 PK     NO
 12345  88888
 78912  99999
 56892  11111
```

table_C

```
  PK    NO
  12345 NET
  78782 SMART
  12345 MMS
  12345 SMART
  56892 MMS
  78912 GT
```

Note in table_C: if PK has 1 to 3 values, get the NO values and populate as C1 C2 C3.

OUTPUT

```
 PK     A      C1   C2    C3     B
 12345  22222  NET  MMS  SMART   88888
 78912  33333  GT               99999
 56892  44444  MMS              11111
 78782         SMART
```

Comment: What is the maximum amount of rows per PK in table c? Will there always  be a row in table a and/or table b for each PK?

Comment: Maximum is 3. Yes there is always a row in table a and b for each PK.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you on the right track.

```
SELECT pk,
       a_no,
       c1,
       IF(c2 = c1,NULL,c2) c2,
       IF(c3 = c2,NULL,c3) c3,
       b_no
FROM(
  -- Separate the 3 table_C NO values into columns.
  SELECT pk, a_no,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(c_no,',',-1) c1,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(c_no,',',-2),',',1 ) c2,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(c_no,',',-3),',',1 ) c3,
         b_no
  FROM (
    -- Condense to 1 row per PK, grouping the table_C NO values
    SELECT pk,
           MAX(a_no) a_no,
           MAX(b_no) b_no,
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c_no) c_no
    FROM(
      -- Get the full outer join list of pks from:
      -- * PKS in table_A, table_B
      -- * PKS only in table_C
      SELECT a.pk, a.no a_no, b.no b_no, c.no c_no
      FROM   table_A a
      LEFT JOIN table_B b ON (a.pk = b.pk)
      LEFT JOIN table_C c ON (a.pk = c.pk)
      UNION
      SELECT c.pk, null, null, c.no
      FROM table_C c
    ) q
    GROUP BY pk
  ) q
) q
;
```